# Session some of data losing MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, session

Our main project MVC 5. I'm always using Session object with no problem. But in a case, I got a problem. Usually, we are using 4 main session key. That's works fine. That keys assigning at controller level filter.

Recently we develop something and should be shared data across application and specific to the session. So, I assigned the value to the session and I can see and use the same action of the controller. But there is a problem, for example, I refresh the page or click something and trigger an action, my session key not there.

We are using InProc and Session timeout 60. Also, there is not a problem with other session keys. The problem occurs even right after refreshing the page.

What is wrong with this usage?

```
    /// Index of some controller
    public virtual ActionResult Index(string key)
{
    if(InquiryId == 1){
    var result = RequestClient("...");
    InquiryId = result.Id;
    }
...
}
```

In base controller its the related part;

```
 public int InquiryId
        {
            get
            {
                if (Session["InquiryId"] != null)
                {
                    return (int)Session["InquiryId"];
                }
                return 1;
            }
            protected set
            {
                _inquiryId = value;
                HttpContext.Session.Add("InquiryId", value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try to use TempData or ViewBag, ViewData instead of Session

Comment: Thank you for advice. But I don't need that id on view. I need for backend jobs or something.

Comment: OK, but you can use  TempData

Comment: But some other reason like redirect and back/forward function on the browser, tempdata can be null. We already tried and got nothing. There is strange behaviour on Session object, we are trying to find why?

Comment: Could you try and set the key in the first line of the Index action ? The RequestClient has the correct result ?

Comment: @NickPolideropoulos hello, I tried and I can get with that. But when I refresh the page, only that session data goes away.

Comment: @orhun.begendi could you post more of your code? Or a sample repo that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
Session.Timeout = 60; // 60 is number of minutes
```

Also you may configure Session timeout by the following key in web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: As I mention. Already done that. Also its not explaning losing some data and persistent some of it.